# How do I delete from immediately AFTER cursor to first non-whitespace character in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a command to delete from the position after the cursor to the first non-whitespace character on the same line.  I've tried several possibilities, and nothing seems to work.  d2w comes closest, but deletes the character under the cursor.

e.g. I want to change this code

```
    $obj->
    set('foo')->
    and('bar');
```

(note the leading spaces!) to

```
    $obj->set('foo')->and('bar');
```

So I place the cursor on the first `>`, hit d2w, and end up with `$obj-set('foo')->` on a single line.  Note the missing '>'.

What's the answer?

Thanks!

Comment: In this case, you want to join. Try 2J. It will join three lines to single line. Is this what you wanted but asked in a different way? Or, you wanted is correct but your example is a special case like what I said?

Comment: Close, but doesn't quite work (especially when doing multiple lines in one go) as it leaves a space between each one.  Jx removes the space if only doing one join, but if you do 4Jx that doesn't help much.  Any suggestions?

Comment: 3gJ would have worked, right?

Comment: `3gJ` would be the answer, I think @SibiCoder you should post it as an answer. However if there are leading spaces in the lines, this may not work. OP didn't specify it either...

Comment: OK, then I will analyse the special cases and add as part of answer.

Comment: Yes, there are leading spaces, sorry.  Stackoverflow obviously uses the first four spaces to designate a code block, and I neglected to add extra spaces!  I'll edit my example.

Comment: I would simply do it with `JxJx`.

Comment: Closely related to http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/439/how-to-join-lines-without-producing-a-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`J` joins the current line with next line, but with a space, but deletes leading spaces in next line.

`gJ` joins the current line with next line without space, but if second line contained leading space, it would be kept as it is. You can add a count before it to join n lines, like `3gJ`

Example:

```
   `3gJ` - join three consecutive lines without spaces.
```

In your case,

```
     Jx - Join two lines with space and delete space
```

Give this command two times, like `JxJx` for your case.

You can't give 2Jx, since J and x are two operators and 2 will be taken only for J alone.  Further, gJ won't work in your case if second line contains leading spaces.